# Prism 7, WPF (.NetCore), DevExpress and ribbon - integration

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, prism

how to build the module application where each module adds its own RibbonPage control?
I've spent hours looking in the internet - but without any success

shell:

```
<dxr:RibbonControl Name="shellRibbonControl" DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.RibbonPageRegion}">
                <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory />
            </dxr:RibbonControl>
```

Module:

Module:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.RibbonPageRegion, typeof(ModuleARibbonPage));
```

Nothing happens - just nothing
I've tried redesign founded examples from pisrm 4, 6 but they use MEF(bootstrap) witch is deprecated now

Thank you in advance for for help and answer

Comment: How does your region adapter for the ribbon look like? I think, there's one from dev express

Answer (score 0):

I don’t use RibbonControl, but I can tell you the approach briefly. The RibbonControl in the Shell holds a Region, or multiple Regions. The module defines the RibbonPage. You treat the RibbonPage as a View with the MVVM pattern. On module initialization time, you register the RibbonPage to the Region in the Shell. BTW, one module can contain multiple RibbonPages.